# jQuery ui dialog image for the title

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, title

Is it possible when specifying a jQuery UI dialog box, to have an image be placed for my title instead of just plain text?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can provide any HTML as the `title` option, like this:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
  title: '<img src="myImage.jpg" />'
});​​​​​​​​​​​
```

[You can see an example in action here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/HaZ9S/)

---

Or, as another demo to annoy the hell out of your users, [you could do this](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/bUvyh/):

```
$("<div />").dialog({
  title: '<marquee>Hello</marquee>'
});​
```

Comment: Haha! Love those!  Thank you so much.  Any other effects such as the `<marquee>`?

Comment: Actually, how would you recommend centering the image in the dialog title?

Comment: LOL, nice. Haven't seen the marquee for a while

Comment: @all 
From version 1.10 title is consider as text, and this solution doesn't work unless you apply this override: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14488774/using-html-in-a-dialogs-title-in-jquery-ui-1-10

Comment: I can't get this to work :( all it does is show the text

Answer (score 0):

You can set it using HTML as well, Though dialog takes text as title but you can change it by extending dialog property like

```
    $(document).ready(function() {   

        $.widget("ui.dialog", $.extend({}, $.ui.dialog.prototype, {
    _title: function(title) {
        var $title = this.options.title || '&nbsp;'
        if( ("titleIsHtml" in this.options) && this.options.titleIsHtml == true )
            title.html($title);
        else title.text($title);
    }
     }));



  $('div#thedialogg').dialog({ 
         title:"<img src='images/logo-new.png' class='logo_size'>",
         titleIsHtml:true,
         autoOpen: false,
         height: 581,
         width: 1000,   
         modal: false,
         draggable: false,
         resizable: false,
         position: 'center'

     })
})
```