# Need to change jquery dialog title bar image

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I tried to change the jQuery dialog title bar image using the below code but it does not work.

My dialog & title bar image look like this:

[image]

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    title: '<img src="myImage.jpg" />'
});​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Any advise on how to change it? Thanks

Comment: It should, what did you try? Does that image exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to add a CSS rule:

```
.ui-dialog-titlebar{
    background:url(http://www.elementalsurface.com/beech-wood.jpg);
}​
```

see the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p5ZJV/)

Answer (score 1):

This code will give a very good idea how to do this:

**jQuery:**

```
var $Dialog_div;

function fnOpenDialog() {
    $Dialog_div = $('<div id=\'ThisDialog\'>Hello</div>').prependTo('body');

    $Dialog_div = $('#ThisDialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        draggable: true,
        resizable: true,
        title: 'Dialogimage<img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x30/000/fff&text=I\'m+an+image,+hi!" />',
        modal: true,
        stack: true,
        height: ($(window).height() * 0.95),
        width: ($(window).width() * 0.9),  
        buttons: {
            'OK': function() {
                $Dialog_div.dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });  
}

$('#ClickMe').click(fnOpenDialog);​
```

**HTML:**

```
<!-- This is more than likely an Adobe issue where it thinks it should be in the front
     all the time no matter what however it is very annoying that you can't open
     a dialog over a PDF-->

<body>
    <div id='ClickMe'>Click here!</div>
    <br/>
    <div></div>
    <br/>      
</body>
```

(It might be a coincidence that the image of your dialog is quite similar to sample here: [jQuery ui dialog image for the title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543532/jquery-ui-dialog-image-for-the-title) :))

**Working demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/V5NkV/ or http://jsfiddle.net/V5NkV/10/

Click on the `click me` in the demo above and you will see the dialog window with small image inside it.

**Good read link:**

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Comment: i want to use other image instead of gray title bar image...how to do it.

Comment: Saweet @Thomas http://jsfiddle.net/V5NkV/10/  or http://jsfiddle.net/V5NkV/5/ AHHHAAA! got you, see below just change `..ui-dialog-titlebar` and you can change title to image, have a nice one, cheerios!