# Using HTML in a Dialog's title in jQuery UI 1.10

Tags: jquery-ui

http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.10/#changed-title-option-from-html-to-text

jQuery UI 1.10 made it so that the dialog title can only be text (no html) to prevent scripting vulnerabilities. I'm not allowing user input to generate this title, so I would still like to use HTML, mainly to display an icon to the left of the title.

I'm going to post my solution to this problem because I haven't seen anyone else ask or answer this yet. Hopefully it will help someone else, or someone else may have a better approach.

More info as to why they did it: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6016

Answer (score 80, accepted):

This will override the function used when setting jQuery UI dialog titles, allowing it to contain HTML.

```
$.widget("ui.dialog", $.extend({}, $.ui.dialog.prototype, {
    _title: function(title) {
        if (!this.options.title ) {
            title.html("&#160;");
        } else {
            title.html(this.options.title);
        }
    }
}));
```

Comment: thanks, at one point i was setting the html manually via attributes, that fixes this problem, thanks

Answer (score 15):

If you hesitate to override jQuery's _title method, you can use the html, append, or similar methods on the title element at the jQuery dialog's open event, like so:

```
$("#element").dialog({
  open: function() {
    $(this).find("span.ui-dialog-title").append("<span class='title'>" + subtitle + "</span>");
  }
});
```

The above parses the HTML correctly while bypassing jQuery's title method.  And since it happens at the open event, the user experience remains seamless.  Just did this on a project, and it worked beautifully.

Comment: If you use `open` it will keep appending. In this case the `create` is the right event. http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-create

Comment: Whether or not you'd use the create function, ADD a scope of somekind!! e.g. `create: function () {                    $(this).siblings().find(".ui-dialog-title").html('<strong>my html title</strong>'); }`

Comment: @Rudy Create would do it too, but open was what worked best in that particular case.  Whether using open, create, or some future, yet-written option, the method of choice for this is more about the particular implementation...unless there's something I'm missing about open that makes this a serious no-no.  If there is, do tell.

Comment: @321X Agreed. I cut off too much in trying to create a simple example. I'm editing my response now.  TY for catching it.

Comment: @luzmcosta `open`: event triggered at every open of dialog, `create`: event triggered ONCE at creation of dialog. If you use `html()` instead of `append()` it's OK, you only waste CPU resources, but the `append()` appends at each open of dialog. Have you inspected the title of dialog after a few `open`  events?

Comment: @Rudy In-browser stress tests are imperative; Wouldn't go to production without them.  The difference between the situation you're describing and the implementation I simplified above is my app emptied or otherwise updated that view at or before close, so I didn't encounter the issue you're describing.  Generally, I found it best to dispose of views as soon as they weren't needed, so when open was triggered, I didn't have flashes of ghost views unless I needed that behavior. Thus, append worked best in my case.  I can't speak to every case.

Comment: I had to wrap it in a `setTimeout`, but it works -- thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This will modify the title after init the dialog

```
$('#element').dialog(options);

var dialogTitle = $('#element').closest('.ui-dialog').find('.ui-dialog-title');
dialogTitle.html('<strong>hello world</strong>');
```