# jquery dialog not allowing html in title

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

have a dialog in which I have the the title_html: option set to true but it still escapes the html so the title shows the code rather than the icon.

Anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```
  <div id="resend_confirmation_dialog" >
    <div class="well-warning">
      Are you sure you want to resend this invitation?
    </div>
  </div>
```

Triggered like this:

```
$(".confirm-resend").on("click", function(e) {
        var link = this;

        e.preventDefault();

        console.log('resend button clicked');
        $( "#resend_confirmation_dialog" ).removeClass('hidden').dialog({
                            resizable: true,
                            autoOpen: true,
                            modal: false,
                            title_html: true,
                            title: "<h4 class='smaller'><i class='icon-warning-sign red'></i> Are you Sure</h4>",

                            buttons: {
                                "Ok": function() {
                                    window.location = link.href;
                                },
                                "Cancel": function() {
                                    $(this).dialog("close");
                                }
                            }
                });
        }
    );
```

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14488774/1883647)

Comment: Looked at that answer but it doesn't seem to meet my needs, I am setting up the dialog differently and this question is trying to understand why the title_html: true option isn't working. Surely it is supposed ot allow injection of html into the title no?

Comment: You should be able to essentially do what that answer is doing (using jQuery's `.html()` function) to set HTML inside of the title node after creating your dialog. Have you tried that? Did you read the links in the question that point to jQuery UI changing the behavior to not allow HTML injection (due to XSS vulnerabilities) and suggesting that you have to override the `_title()` method of the dialog widget to inject HTML, which is what that answer is doing? That answer is exactly what the jQuery UI documentation says to do, and is what you're going to need to do.

Comment: There's a second answer there that provides an alternative (use the dialog's `create` event to `.append()` HTML), but it feels like more of a workaround.

Comment: yes, you are right, I managed to get this to work with _title . Thanks for the pointers.