# Force JQuery Dialog Title to Multiple Lines

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

How can I force a jQuery Dialog's Title to always be two lines?

See this: http://jsfiddle.net/VKcJ7/24/

I know the dialog title is contained in a span, so I'm not sure if this is possible. I want the 'SOME ITEM' portion to always be on the first line, and the 'Remaining qty...' portion to always be on the second line.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        title: 'SOME ITEM \n Remaining Qty (Cts.): 0'
        //adding the newline character \n is ignored...
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-title {
    white-space:normal;
}
```

Comment: @RobertHarvey a <br/> is just added as part of the title text

Comment: I guess you'll have to hack the jQuery Dialog source code then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using the answer of this question (thanks @jazZRo): 
[Using HTML in a Dialog's title in jQuery UI 1.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14488774/using-html-in-a-dialogs-title-in-jquery-ui-1-10)
to extend the widget.

I then set my title as follows: (Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/VKcJ7/30/)

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        title: 'SOME ITEM <br> Remaining Qty (Cts.): 0'
        //adding the newline character \n is ignored...
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Officially, I don't think you can.

The hacky way is to jam it in:

```
$("#dialog")
    .dialog({
      autoOpen: false
    })
    .closest(".ui-dialog")
      .find(".ui-dialog-title")
        .html("Dialog<br>Title");
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/rokah/1/edit) | [With `resizable: true`](http://jsbin.com/rokah/2)

[image: jQuery UI Dialog with Multi-line title]

But again, fairly hacky.

Comment: If you want multiple lines more often, consider extending the widget: [see this stackoverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14488774/using-html-in-a-dialogs-title-in-jquery-ui-1-10)