# JQuery UI Dialgo modal's title html tags is not rendered

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-ui-dialog

I am currently adding modal to my application. When modal is displayed it also shows the html tags inside modal title.
[image: screen]

As you see dialog title is not rendered and it shows html tags. Here it is dialog html

```
<div id="dialog_simple" title="Dialog Simple Title">
  <p>
   Dialog part is woring just fine.
  </p>

</div>
```

And here related javascript to open modal

```
$('#dialog_link').click(function() {
        $('#dialog_simple').dialog('open');
        return false;
  });


 $('#dialog_simple').dialog({
          autoOpen : false,
          width : 600,
          resizable : false,
          modal : true,
          title : "<div class='widget-header'><h4><i class='fa fa-warning'></i> Empty the recycle bin?</h4></div>",
          buttons : [{
            html : "<i class='fa fa-trash-o'></i>&nbsp; Delete all items",
            "class" : "btn btn-danger",
            click : function() {
              $(this).dialog("close");
            }
          }, {
            html : "<i class='fa fa-times'></i>&nbsp; Cancel",
            "class" : "btn btn-default",
            click : function() {
              $(this).dialog("close");
            }
          }]
        });

        })
```

Am I missing something? Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like you're wrapping Bootstrap's Modal plugin with your own. Make sure that `title` isn't treating it as plain text but rather HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is not related to Bootstrap.
From what I can see you are using jQuery UI Dialog (http://jqueryui.com/dialog/), right?

The title property only accepts a string but you can overwrite the default behaviour as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14488776/3215856

Comment: @HarunErgül you should mention that in your post. That's important info.

Comment: Actually I realized it  when you said that

Comment: @HarunErgül This is not even related to Front-End. You got a problem, which you would like to solve. If you don't know the answer, you ask on the internet on an specific topic for a certain problem. Don't feel ashamed, it just makes things way easier if they are more explicit :)

Could you also please update the title and tags. I suggest removing the wording "Bootstrap" at all and replace it by "jQuery UI Dialog"

Comment: @marcobiedermann i am developing a Django based CRUD application. It is a personal project. I am trying  to improve my font-end and back-end skills together. Thanks for feedback